# Youtube Data Api v3. How to get the latest video added to playlist

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get the latest video posted to a playlist using Youtube Data Api.
If I do this

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId=<id>
```

It will get the videos from the list sorted from oldest to newest and paginated. If I want to get the latest all that I can think of is iterating over the pages until I get to the last one and picking the last item in the last page.

Anybody knows a better way to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this with the current api version. A workaround might be to instead perform a search such that your request looks like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=playlistItems&order=date&channelId=<ChannelId>&maxResults=20&playlistId=<PlaylistId>&key=<ApiKey>
```

Comment: sadly, `type=playlistItems` is not an acceptable value for the parameter `type` [Source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)